# Disable Google Analytics in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Google Analytics is running in the iOS simulator.

This causes pollution in the console log which I can be looking for useful debugging information. Also, the data sent to Google is not indicative of an actual user using our app.

How can I disable the Google Analytics reporting just while running the app in iOS simulator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple, this is taken straight from the Google Analytics webpage :

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:YES];
```

> Dry Run :
>   The SDK provides a dryRun flag that when set, prevents any data from being sent to Google Analytics. The dryRun flag should be set whenever you are testing or debugging an implementation and do not want test data to appear in your Google Analytics reports.

Hope this helps

Comment: Need to wrap this in: #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR #endif

Comment: Is there a way to also not have Google Analytics pollute my console logs?

Comment: You could just go to the NSLogs in the source and comment it out.... not to sure if there is another way

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Setting DryRun to YES will fix this issue.

@Full Decent - Is there a way to also not have Google Analytics pollute my console logs?

We can disable Google Analytics logging in Xcode console using the below method.

`[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelNone];`

Or in Swift:

`GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.None`

Comment: Added the answer in Swift as well

Comment: Unfortunately its not working for me and GAI still spamming me with all kind of log messages :-( GoogleAnalytics v3.14.0, GoogleUtilities v1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it in `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR #endif` will not work in **swift**, as that flag is for **objective-c** only.
What you could do is follow this guide

[Detect if app is being built for device or simulator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869481/detect-if-app-is-being-built-for-device-or-simulator-in-swift/37124071#37124071)