# What's wrong with my #if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR code for Realm path definition?

Tags: swift, realm

I have this code

```
 #if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
let device = false
let RealmDB = try! Realm(path: "/Users/Admin/Desktop/realm/Realm.realm")
#else
let device = true
let RealmDB = try! Realm()
#endif
```

device bool works fine, yet RealmDB works only for else condition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` macro doesn't work in Swift.
What you want to do is like the following, right?

```
#if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
let device = false
let RealmDB = try! Realm(path: "/Users/Admin/Desktop/realm/Realm.realm")
#else
let device = true
let RealmDB = try! Realm()
#endif
```

Comment: Please don't use architecture as a shortcut for simulator.

Comment: Swift has targetEnvironment. This is no longer the correct way to define the simulator.

Answer (score 45):

As of Xcode 9.3+ Swift now supports `#if targetEnvironment(simulator)` to check if you're building for Simulator.

Please stop using architecture as a shortcut for simulator. Both macOS and the Simulator are x86_64 which might not be what you want.

```
// ObjC/C:
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    // for sim only
#else
    // for device
#endif


// Swift:
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    // for sim only
#else
    // for device
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

Please see this post. This is the correct way to do it and it's well explained

https://samsymons.com/blog/detecting-simulator-builds-in-swift/

Basically define a variable named as you like (maybe 'SIMULATOR') to be set during run in simulator.
Set it in Build Settings of Target, under `Active Compilation Conditions`- > `Debug` then `(+)` then choose `Any iOS Simulator SDK` in the dropdown list, then add the variable.

Then in your code

```
var isSimulated = false
#if SIMULATOR
  isSimulated = true // or your code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

More explanation about this issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869481/detect-if-app-is-being-built-for-device-or-simulator-in-swift).
I am using [this](http://themainthread.com/blog/2015/06/simulator-check-in-swift.html) approach:

```
struct Platform {
        static let isSimulator: Bool = {
            var isSim = false
            #if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
                isSim = true
            #endif
            return isSim
        }()
    }

    // Elsewhere...

    if Platform.isSimulator {
        // Do one thing
    }
    else {
        // Do the other
    }
```

Or create a utility class:

```
class SimulatorUtility
{

    class var isRunningSimulator: Bool
    {
        get
        {
             return TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR != 0// for Xcode 7
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply! the thing is that i can put that "if Platform.isSimulator" inside some class, yet i need to set that constant "let RealmDB..." on the top level right after "import RealmSwift".

Comment: Please do NOT use architecture as a shortcut for simulator.