# When submitting a swift based cocoapod, I get this error when checking if the device is a simulator: code after 'return' will never be executed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am attempting to submit a cocoapod written in Swift that contains the following code method intended to prevent execution of specific code when targeting a simulator:

```
func isDevice() -> Bool {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        return false
    #endif

    return true
}
```

While XCode finds this acceptable, and I can suppress the warning from `pod lib lint` with the `--allow-warnings` flag, attempting to submit the pod will still fail.

This code produces the warning `warning: code after 'return' will never be executed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake I made was that while the [source of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869481/detect-if-app-is-being-built-for-device-or-simulator-in-swift/24869607#24869607) is solid, I did not properly implement the conditional check.

Below is the proper way to do it to avoid issues with the Cocoapod validation:

```
func isDevice() -> Bool {
        #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
            return false
        #else
            return true
        #endif
    }
```

By placing the check inside the `#if...#endif`, I was able to avoid the warning.