# Detect if app running on simulator or device in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift

Although this question has been asked many times in older environments, when I try to run @mbelsky's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124071/846273) on a device running iOS 11.2, the simulator block of the code below runs, rather than the device block.  When I run the code on the simulator, the simulator runs as expected.

```
@IBOutlet weak var testSimulatorFlag: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        #if IOS_SIMULATOR
            testSimulatorFlag.text = "Compiler thinks this is a simulator"
        #else
            testSimulatorFlag.text = "Compiler thinks this is a device"
        #endif
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of how the project's Swift-Compiler, Custom Flags is set:

[image: Screenshot]

[Here](https://github.com/blakeprobinson/testSimulatorFlag) is a sample project that demonstrates the issue. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: @AshvinGudaliya, I am aware of that question, but I am asking a new question because the suggested answer to the old question isn't working for me.

Comment: Are you sure that you followed the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124071/1187415 correctly? Unless I am mistaken, you defined the custom flag for the Debug configuration, and not just for the iOS Simulator SDK.

Comment: @MartinR, I added a screenshot to make sure I'm implementing the custom flag correctly

Comment: @Blake: Unless I a mistaken, the flag must only be defined in the "Any iOS Simulator SDK" row,  *not* in the "Debug" row.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, you are correct.  Removing that solved my issue.  Thanks very much!

Comment: So it *is* a duplicate ...

Answer (score 10):

I have found the most reliable way is:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    testSimulatorFlag.text = "Compiler thinks this is a simulator"
#else
    testSimulatorFlag.text = "Compiler thinks this is a device"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to avoid using that approach since a compiler flag seems more robust, but, if I can't get to the bottom of why the compiler flag isn't producing expected results, then I will use this solution.